# Replacing a letter in a string into another letter

Tags: c

So after I learnt C completely I'll make a program which save the password of the user in their computer(local), but saving password in local is dangerous since the people who know where is the password saved can get the password easily I am tying to code a encoder that replace every letter with a specific letter. (Example: 'a' into '1') So I tried the code at ideone.com: (Since I am not nearby my computer but a smartphone)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char input;

    scanf("%c", &input);
    encode(input);
    printf("%c", input);

    return 0;
}

void encode(char input) {
    char a = 'a';
    char A = 'A';

    a = '1';
    A = '2';
}
```

It should be displayed as "12" if I entered "aA", but of course it only display an 'a' since a char only save the first word into the variable. I did tried using the [10] after the char but I got the error, and without it it only display an 'a' which didn't being replaced. Please answer me ASAP.

Comment: "*I learnt C completely*", really, did you?

Comment: @alk Anyway sorry for my English if you didn't know what I am saying.

Comment: You are doing nothing in encode other than assigning 2 characters. If you remove the encode call in main you will get the same result. On the other hand `printf("%c",...)` prints out 1 character, that's what the %c stands for. If you want to print a series of characters (e.g. a word) , you should use `%s` instead.

Comment: P.S: "Please answer me ASAP" won't get you any friends here!

Comment: Note that a 'monoalphabetic substitution cipher' such as you seem to be proposing is so weak that it is used in newspapers for entertainment.  As a security mechanism for a password, it doesn't even register as marginally secure.

Comment: @hhachem Thanks for advice. Thisis my first time to use ASAP in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach has two big issues.

1. donot use 'void' use 'int' as 'encode' return type. Pass all the values entered by the user as characters using a for loop and save the returning 'int' values in an 'int' array. After that you can display that array to the user that the password has been encoded or encrypted.
2. you are not using the ' char input' anywhere in the encode function, therefore nothing is being changed.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean that I wanted the letter converted into ASCII one, but instead the specifif word, just like 'a' into 'v'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to scan in an array of characters (using %s and a char array), and then loop through replacing charcters according to your mappings. Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Note we pass a pointer here, which gives access to the array... */
void encode(char *input) 
{
    int i;

    /* Loop through until we hit the end-of-string character */
    for (i=0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        switch (input[i])
        {
            case 'a':
                input[i] = '1';
                break;
            case 'A':
                input[i] = '2';
                break;

            /* Add more mappings here, as required... */

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* Make sure this is big enough for your string... */
    char input[10];

    scanf("%s", input);
    encode(input);
    printf("%s", input);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that 'switch' here is only useful if you have a few specific mappings. If you want to translate characters in a more flexible way, you might want to do some kind of mathematical operation on the value of the char - that side of things is up to you!

Comment: Nearly good.  I'd like to encourage `"%9s"` for the `scanf()` format, especially when the buffer is as short as just 10 bytes. How do you plan to extend the switch to cover the entire alphabet?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Extending it is an exercise for the OP - this is just trying to point them in the right direction!

Comment: I'm glad you're trying to point them in the right direction; so am I. I'm questioning whether a switch statement is the right direction.  I think not. … — Your latest edit is definitely better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Agreed, and thanks for the suggestion - I've updated my post, indicating that the switch solution is far from ideal for lots of mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Your `encode` method has no effect at all. Passed by value. That never affects the variable input. It'll display the input that you are given.

You have to send the Address of the character variable. Read [Pass by reference](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_language%3aTerms%3aPass_by_reference)